# C++/Qt - Seg. fault on 32 bits Linux, but not on 64 bits Windows?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, x86-64

I have a segmentation fault on my small laptop Linux 32 bits, whereas I don't on my 64 bits windows. I don't know if it comes from the Qt Version, the arch or the OS...

Anyway, here's the error found by Valgrind :

```
Invalid read of size 4 in Board::movePawns(Case*) in board.cpp:157
  1: std::_List_iterator&lt;PawnLabel*&gt;::operator++(int) dans <a href="file:///usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:163" >/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_list.h:163</a>
```

It seems that it the "operator++" is causing a problem.

Heres the complete code of this part :

```
void Board::movePawns(Case* c)
{
int trouve = 0;
int i;
int j;

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<3;j++){

        if(&(this->board[i][j]) == c)
           break;
    }
    if(&(this->board[i][j]) == c)
       break;
}

PawnLabel* toMove = NULL;

list<PawnLabel*>::iterator it;
list<PawnLabel*>::iterator toMove_iterator;
Case* oldCase;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){

                for (it=this->board[i][j].pawnList.begin(); it != this->board[i][j].pawnList.end(); ++it)
                {
                    if((*it)->getSelected() == 1)
                    {
                        toMove_iterator = it;
                        toMove = *toMove_iterator;
                        trouve = 1;
                        oldCase = &(this->board[i][j]);
                    }
                }

        }
    }

    toMove = *toMove_iterator;

    if(trouve == 1)
    {
        if(oldCase == c)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Impossible : pion deja sur la case";
        }
        else
        {

            for(toMove_iterator;toMove_iterator != oldCase->pawnList.end();toMove_iterator++)
            {
                toMove = *toMove_iterator; // SOUS LINUX (OU ARCH 32 BITS ?) toMove est n'importe quoi dès la première itération

                insertPawn(c,toMove);
                removePawn(oldCase,toMove);
                toMove->setSelected(0);

            }
        }
    }
```

}

I really don't understand. I know that it screws up with the iterator, but I can't see why it works on one of my computer and not the other one.

EDIT : I added the full function.

Could be that I delete the elements in the same time that I go through the list, but then how to do it properly ?

Comment: Let's hope that trouve has been initialized properly. (The search loop could exit after trouve = 1.)

Comment: Code is indeed not complete. I'm also missing `c`.

Comment: More seriously, just a suggestion, don't compare to .end() using !=. because .end() +1 is != to .end() even though it's just as invalid.

Comment: You really need to indent your code to be more readable. Also, please use C++11 if you can. The iteration would be simpler at the end with range based for.

Comment: Please, translate your comment in English, do not use French